# How to synchronize a GitHub fork?

Tags: github, synchronize, git-fork

I'm trying to follow instruction found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/), but it fails on the very first step:

```
C:\wxFork [master +42 ~0 -32 !]> git fetch upstream
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What do I do?

Thank you.

Comment: You nee to configure the upstream first : https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/

Comment: @T.Claverie, thank you. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `upstream` first by adding it explicitly to your list of `remote`s:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

Doing a `git remote -v` should show your `upstream` and now the `git fetch upstream` should work for you